# is it possible to send only error logs to event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

I created a diagnostics setting in azure apim and send logs to event hub.

But now the requirement is I need to pass only the error logs from azure api management to event hub.Current setting passes all the success and failure logs into event hub.

is there any way to filter logs before sending it into event hub or log only errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this I would check response status code and only send to eventhub in case of an error in `outbound` section e.g. of the `all operations` policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode.ToString() >= "400")">
                <log-to-eventhub logger-id ="ehLogger">
                    @(...)
                </log-to-eventhub>        
            </when>
            <otherwise>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id ="ehLogger">
            @(...)
        </log-to-eventhub>        
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

This is for response errors from the backend. If you're referring to errors happening in request / policy processing, you would only send from `on-error` section. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies) for more information.